# Datagridview to Array Issue

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview, format, datasource

Currently have a C# program with two datagridviews, one with streaming data and another with calculated data. I currently run the below code to generate the MSChart:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList array_name = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
array_name.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    array_name.Add(this.dataGridViewData[4, i].Value);

System.Collections.ArrayList array_contract = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
array_contract.Clear();
for (int x = 0; x < 48; x++)
   array_contract.Add(this.dataGridViewData[0, x].Value);

chart2.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(array_contract, array_name);
```

This works fine!

What I am having an issue with is running the same above code, but passing it into another datagridview (dataGridView1). For some odd reason, this code isnt working for me:

```
            try
        {

            System.Collections.ArrayList array_strip = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
            for (int tt = 0; tt < 5; tt++)
                array_strip.Add(this.dataGridViewData[4, tt].Value);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = array_strip;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("E(c) " + ex);
        }
```

When I run the above code I am getting incorrect results. The actual number it should be showing is 3.010 throughout the new dataGridView1.

This is what the first dataGridViewData looks like:
Name, Price, Price 2, Price 3, Price 4 and change.
John, 3.1, 3.00, 3.02, 3.01, -.04.

After further digging into the issue, when I run the above code, the datagridview1 returns the string number, not the value of the cells. Im looking for a solution on how to convert the returned data (16 - the characters) into the actual data.

Comment: try wrapping {} around your for statement for starters.. this inline formatting can be hard to read at times... your variable names should be more meaningful as well nothing worse than seeing single or double alpha chars as counter incrementers.. GRRR

Comment: Im just getting results that are not accurate. Basically, it should be passing column 4's data, but its passing something else. Im not sure why.

Comment: Made changes to original code to reflect try, catch.

Comment: you should edit that and make it part of your initial post.. it's kind of all over the place in all due respect... also you are not auto generating the DataGridView1 columns are you.. also are the datatypes of the datagridviews columns for the expected results of the correct datatype.. and are you doing proper binding..?

Comment: what is the problem actually? Spits out at 16 means?

Comment: If you just bind a nongeneric collection like an arraylist like that using `DataSource` property, its not gonna work. The gridview doesnt know which property to be shown since all the elements in an arraylist are objects. Can you use list<T> control? Or manually add to datagridview?